# What happened to the top bar and it's restored now

Tags: discussion, support, design, mobile-web, top-bar

When I refreshed the page it suddenly looks like this.

[image: new]

This is what it previously was

[image: old]

What happened?

---

Edit: Seems to have been restored at 17:48 UTC, January 23.

Too bad that [a bug is introduced immediately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362411/5958455).

Comment: [An immediate bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362411/5958455).

Comment: Even I got surprised at this sudden change!

Comment: @WrichikBasu I think animuson meant "all updates are pushed and deployed to surprise users, and if the reaction is too hot we retract it".

Comment: @iDebug hmmmm. But before the change in top bar of desktop version, there was an announcement...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a project underway to bring the mobile theme more inline with the design of the full site, including the new top bar and some experiments with vertical navigation that haven't been fully realized yet.

This... Clearly needs a bit more time to bake, so we've reverted the change pending further testing. We'll make a full announcement when/if this goes live again, but not until reviewing all the bugs already reported today under [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web).

Sorry for the confusion and major thanks for everyone's help identifying areas that need work!

---

Bugs we're currently aware of:

- Stacked Icons: [Stacked icons on new top bar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362411/stacked-icons-on-new-top-bar)
- Long names push site nav off screen: [Misalignment in top bar on mobile web on sites with long names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306117/misalignment-in-top-bar-on-mobile-web-on-sites-with-long-names) and also [Can't switch between sites while on my mod site on new mobile web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306116/cant-switch-between-sites-while-on-my-mod-site-on-new-mobile-web)
- Safari 6 doesn't collapse new nav: [The new menu on mobile versions of SE sites is open all the time in older browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306122/the-new-menu-on-mobile-versions-of-se-sites-is-open-all-the-time-in-older-browse)
- Home is not translated yet: ["Home" is not translated on localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306119/home-is-not-translated-on-localized-sites)
- Questions are called "Stack Overflow" on all sites: ["Stack Overflow" showing up on hamburger menu for all sites to link to /questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306115/stack-overflow-showing-up-on-hamburger-menu-for-all-sites-to-link-to-question)
- No color indication of main and meta: [No differentiation between main and meta sites on mobile web anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306118/no-differentiation-between-main-and-meta-sites-on-mobile-web-anymore)

Comment: If I observed bugs while it was up, is it worth reporting them now, or should I wait until it's live?

Comment: Can... Can you guys *please* dedicate the energy into fixing the app first? Honest request.

Comment: If they're not already reported *and* you saved a screenshot or can provide a *very* detailed description, sure @DJMcMayhem. Otherwise, might as well save your energy for the next (hopefully less chaotic) rollout and testing period. Please also include specific information on the device and browser you're using and post them under the [meta-tag:mobile-web] tag.

Comment: I kinda feel like the mobile web is a bit more critical than the app, @totallyhuman... I might be biased, but this is first and foremost a *web site*.

Comment: Fair point with that but I'd say the website is currently in a way more workable condition than the app.

Comment: Probably true, but that's no reason to neglect one. Hopefully we can finish moving to the new top bar / nav systems *without* trashing the usability of the mobile web, and then at some point revisit the apps to bring them in line as well.

Comment: Why not follow recent major changes and let us test here before deploying network wide? This way you: A) prevent confusion for thousands of users, and B) Get proper feedback, and not in the form of panicked bug reports. :)

Comment: @totallyhuman the app is used by tiny fraction on the users, while the mobile web is used by many users.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard I'd think that's *because* the app isn't better.

Comment: @Shog9 While I fully agree that the mobile website is far more important than the apps, the current situation is quite confusing or even outright misleading. The apps are actively advertised, but they do represent an inferior version of the mobile web site currently (I only know the Android version, I'm making assumptions about iOS). How is anyone that isn't an active follower of SE meta supposed to know that the mobile site is actually better, and that they shouldn't complain about the apps?

Comment: @MadScientist more than that, there is no active android/iOS developers in Stack Exchange. The programmers who used to work on the apps have all be reassigned to work on other things, so it means no bugs are fixed and no feature will be added to the apps. They are frozen in time.

Comment: Eh, @shadow, re: testing... Lotta internal discussion on that exact point this morning. We're gonna take another crack at this & get it right, ok?

Comment: And @mad... You're preaching to the choir. But, I do like push notifications. Maybe if we can get to where we're *not* maintaining 4 different designs we can make one that works consistently across mobile and main and apps? Design team has been working hard on trying to make something a bit more flexible than what we've traditionally had here, but it's a slow, painful process.

Comment: @Shog9 yes sir, sounds good. :) BTW think mad wasn't pinged, unless those are not three dots? On mobile now (headed to bed) so hard to tell.

Comment: He got pinged; this isn't chat @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard