# "Stack Overflow" showing up on hamburger menu for all sites to link to /questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

Why does it say "Stack Overflow" instead of the site name?

[image]

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306114/295232 – I can reproduce your issue but not iBug's.

Comment: I dont think it. He or she us working on literarure.stackexchange

Comment: At least it still links to the right page.

Comment: Because Jeff Atwood cast a magic spell and they're all Stack Overflow now :)

Comment: [Reverted - we'll review bug reports and do more extensive testing before continuing here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306114/what-happened-to-the-top-bar-and-its-restored-now/306123#306123)

Comment: Let me "borrow" your image.