# Can't switch between sites while on my mod site on new mobile web

Tags: bug, mobile-web

When I'm on my mod site I have my diamond dropdown:

[image]

But on Meta.SE and other sites, I have the StackBurger:

[image]

This doesn't show on my mod site, so I can't switch between sites easily.

Comment: All the sites I use look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUmun.png

Comment: @snailplane I'm seeing some misalignment as well...

Comment: You need another phone with a bigger screen.

Comment: This is even more extreme on sites with longer names, it breaks most stuff on the right even for regular users there.

Comment: Which device? (this probably depends on screen resolution/density) We've rolled back the change pending a pile'o'fixes, so any details are helpful in testing here. [See also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306114/what-happened-to-the-top-bar-and-its-restored-now/306123#306123)

Comment: @Shog9 - Samsung Galaxy S-75