# Misalignment in top bar on mobile web on sites with long names

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, top-bar

With the roll out of the new top bar on Interpersonal Skills SE I'm seeing a slight misalignment. Looks like the top bar is a bit wider than the rest of the body:

[image]

I'm seeing this in on an Android phone using Chrome.

On other systems/with other preferences, part of the top bar is just invisible (though it can be found by scrolling). These screenshots were made with Firefox 57.0.4 on Android 6.0, 720×1280, ~294 ppi:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try PPCG and it's worse :)

Comment: @iDebug Yikes...

Comment: I just came here to make the same report. I'm seeing something slightly different. I took the liberty to add some screenshots, hope that that's OK.

Comment: Looks like they rolled back that change now by the way :-)

Comment: @Keelan freehand circles are traditionally red, but I won't hold it against you ;)

Comment: It's previously **[Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWoXY.jpg)** Interesting ellipses! You may even see **Programming Puzzles & Code ...** on a smaller screen.

Comment: [Reverted - we'll review bug reports and do more extensive testing before continuing here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306114/what-happened-to-the-top-bar-and-its-restored-now/306123#306123) Mind providing details on the device you're using (this likely depends on screen resolution / density)?

Comment: @Shog9 I added details for my screenshots at the bottom to the post.