# No differentiation between main and meta sites on mobile web anymore

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, per-site-meta

Previously, on mobile web, main sites had a blue bar and meta sites were dark. Now, though, they're both the same color:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And Stack Overflow (main) has an orange-themed white bar.

Comment: And the previous look has been restored all of a sudden.

Comment: [Reverted - we'll review bug reports and do more extensive testing before continuing here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306114/what-happened-to-the-top-bar-and-its-restored-now/306123#306123)