# "Home" is not translated on localized sites

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, mobile-web

[image]

This reads "Home" on esSO, ptSO, ruSO and rus. Strangely enough, the text on jaSO *is* in Japanese and it's the only site with translation.

Comment: Translations are done by those individual communities, so it's possible that "Home" has been translated in Japanese but not by the others yet. It's one of those "will solve itself eventually" kind of things.