# The new menu on mobile versions of SE sites is open all the time in older browsers

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

## Problem

The new mobile menu on all SE sites is open all the time in older web browsers (even directly when you navigate to the page).

Below is a screenshot of how Stack Overflow looks on Safari 6.0 on my iPhone 4 running iOS 6.1.3 (yes I'm still using it):

[image: The menu is open all the time on older browsers]

## Cause

I found that the issue is caused by the CSS-property called `transform`, underlined in the screenshot below:

[image: The 'transform' property is the cause]

Older browsers (like Safari 6.0 in iOS 6) do not support the standard `transform` property. Instead, some of them support prefixed versions of it (from [**W3Schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)):

- `-webkit-transform` (older versions of Safari, Chrome and Opera)
- `-moz-transform` (older versions of Firefox)
- `-ms-transform` (Internet Explorer 9)

## Solution

I suggest these three properties to be added to the CSS as well, for compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: [Reverted - we'll review bug reports and do more extensive testing before continuing here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306114/what-happened-to-the-top-bar-and-its-restored-now/306123#306123) - thanks for the heads-up; we may not be able to fully support older browsers, but we'll try to watch for major breakage.